# Jumper settings for IDE controller

Tags: identify-this-computer, ide

Fitting to my 286 board I have a Multi IO card with IDE and FDC ports. It has a bunch of jumpers, but I have no ID on this. So far, stason.org search hasn't been conclusive. Here is a picture:

[image]

There is a FCC filing listed for the FCC ID on the board: https://fccid.io/J3ITN-171

Redford Company Inc I/O Card TN-171

As a reference to Anonymous' link: these are the jumper descriptions from the linked page:

```
JP2 PTR PORT EN/DIS ENABLE DISABEL
JP3 SIO 0 PORT SELECT COM1 COM3
JP4 FDC EN/DIS ENABLE DISABLE
JP5 SIO 1 EN/DIS ENABLE DISABLE 
JP6 PRINTER PORT SELECT 0378 0278
JP7 SIO 1 PORT SELECT COM2 COM4
JP8 GAME PORT EN/DIS ENABLE DISABLE
JP9 SIO 0 EN/DIS ENABLE DISABLE
JP10 IDE EN/DIS ENABLE DISABLE
JP11 IRQ 3 SIO 1 SIO 2
JP12 IRQ 4 SIO 1 SIO 2
JP13 IRQ 5 SIO 1 SIO 2
JP14 IRQ 2 SIO 1 SIO 2
JP15 PRINTER IRQ SELECT IRQ 7 IRQ 5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some more digging I actually found the card on stason.org:

http://stason.org/TULARC/pc/hard-disk-floppy-controllers/I-L/INFOMATIC-POWER-SYSTEMS-CORPORATION-Two-IDE-AT-Int.html

[image: W83757 based Super I/O card]

The layout and jumpers match exactly, even though it is listed under a different manufacturer.

Comment: This should be the correct answer! Link of other answer is not available anymore

Answer (score 5):

[This document](http://www.driverforum.com/controller/6626.html) should tell you all. These jumpers configure state of the multi I/O card devices, and their port locations. The document states different chip UM82C865F, but the jumper functionality should be the same or similar. At the end of the day you can figure out yourself.

Update: I found datasheet of the W83757 on the alldatasheet.com; there's some information about configuration pins, and if you have multimeter you can carefully trace conductors between chip and jumpers (in multimeter's voltrop "diode sign" mode) and guess about their exact purpose.

Comment: The actual hint with the datasheet was very good. I will keep this in mind for other old hardware I come across, even though I found that particular card already on stason.org.